# Django HTML templating and javascript - convert variable to string

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a dictionary `data` that I want to append a variable from my template to as a string.

```
data = {}

data['name'] = {{ img_obj.name }}
```

However, that just appends the name, not as string. I want it the value to be string.

I tried using the safe filter, that did not work.

Comment: If this is javascript, then like this: data['name'] = img_obj.name

Comment: `data['name'] = "{{ img_obj.name }}"`? Is this in javascript though? I would recommend **not** rendering into javascript it is insecure (potential XSS attacks).